# How to make a simple imgui popup window in C#

Tags: c#, imgui

Im trying to make a simple popup window where i can input text but i am having a hard time getting started.

```
        internal sealed class UpdatelogWindow : Window, IDisposable
    {
        public UpdatelogWindow()
            : base("What's new?", ImGuiWindowFlags.AlwaysAutoResize | ImGuiWindowFlags.NoResize)
        {
            this.Namespace = "Update Window";

            this.Size = new Vector2(885, 463);
            this.SizeCondition = ImGuiCond.Appearing;

        }
        public override void Draw()
        {
            ImGui.Text($"Test.");

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose this window.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This is what i have at the moment but nothing is showing up

Comment: Why are you overriding draw?

Comment: Thats what was suggested to me but clearly isnt right... To clarify i am new to imgui and all i want is a simple popup window.

Comment: if you add base.Draw() to the end of your draw function, does that change what you see?

Comment: Do you intend to go for this hard solution? You can create a WPF or Windows Forms application instead. I think this is much easier for this task. Windows Forms is an old technology but easy to start using. WPF will feel a bit more complicated at first, but is far more flexible in future. You can find lots of tutorials on both technologies.